# How to insert a inner join from 3 different tables

Tags: sql, oracle, view

I am making a view pulling data from 3 different tables for the query. Here is my code so far, I'm just not sure how to integrate the inner joins since I already have a select statement, I can't picture it. A rewrite of my code would be appreciated!

````
AS SELECT c.nutritional_value, i.item_id, i.item_name,
m.sell_price, m.buy_price
FROM consumables c, items i, merchants m
WHERE c.item_id=i.item_id
AND c.item_id=m.item_id```
````

Comment: What is the issue here? Inner join of two tables is already (implicitly and in old-style form) integrated when you place a `where` condition involving both the tables. But it's more readable and easy to debug in ANSI join form, which is nicely explained in [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10002.htm#i2080416) with lots of examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have an inner join; you just wrote it using the legacy comma join syntax rather than the (more modern) ANSI syntax.

```sql
SELECT c.nutritional_value,
       i.item_id,
       i.item_name,
       m.sell_price,
       m.buy_price
FROM   consumables c,         -- The comma indicates a CROSS JOIN
       items i,               -- The comma indicates a CROSS JOIN
       merchants m
WHERE  c.item_id=i.item_id    -- This filter condition implicitly converts the first join to
                              -- an INNER JOIN
AND    c.item_id=m.item_id    -- This filter condition implicitly converts the second join to
                              -- an INNER JOIN
```

If you want to explicitly rewrite it using ANSI syntax then:

- replace the commas with the join type; then
- after the identifier for the table being joined add an `ON` clause containing the join condition.

```sql
SELECT c.nutritional_value,
       i.item_id,
       i.item_name,
       m.sell_price,
       m.buy_price
FROM   consumables c
       INNER JOIN items i     ON c.item_id=i.item_id
       INNER JOIN merchants m ON c.item_id=m.item_id
```

Answer (score 0):

I do this conversion almost daily.  I think the folks that wrote the SQL for one of the applications I work with have extensive experience in VB.  (not SQL)

```
SELECT c.nutritional_value
, i.item_id
, i.item_name
, m.sell_price
, m.buy_price

FROM consumables c
  inner join items i on c.item_id=i.item_id
  inner join merchants m on c.item_id=m.item_id
```